# Modification of stack size by ulimit -s

Tags: application-development, c++, c

When I type `ulimit -s` in terminal it shows `8192`. Does it mean that in my C code I could only have local variable of 8192 bytes?

I am confused which stack size. Does `ulimit -s` change when we modify its value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, it is 8192 **kilo** bytes, and not bytes. Furthermore stack is one thing, variable is another, and heap yet another. See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap) of differences between stack and heap, for example, or [this page](https://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html). As far as I know stack is used for local and short lived variables, and it depends on the compiler whether stack or heap are used.

As far as I can tell, if you use `[mc]alloc` and friends to allocate memory, you are not touching upon the stack, and the limits do not hold.

But yes, trying the following at `ulimit -s` equal to 8192 will result in a segmentation fault:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char foo[10000000] ;
  foo[0] = 'a' ;
  exit( 0 ) ;
}
```

Here, the variable `foo` is too large.

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

However, if you change the ulimit (e.g. `ulimit -s 16000`), it will work.

Comment: How do I know my stack size limit? I mean, which is the maximum number I can write afer `ulimit -s`?